# iOS - Caching and loading images asynchronously

Tags: iphone, image, ios, caching

I want an image loading and caching library for iOS that

- loads images asynchronously,
- caches images, with a configurable cache size and LRU behaviour,
- checks to see if images have been updated, using HTTP HEAD,
- doesn't cache anything in the event of an error code or an invalid image.

I've looked at [HJCache](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/), but it only satisfies the first two of these criteria. Is there something better?

Comment: I wrote MKNetworkKit that exactly does what you want. http://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit ARC based networking + caching framework. LRU Cache, HEAD requests for subsequent loading, ETag support and more...

Comment: I built UIImageLoader which gives you a lot more control over cache control. https://github.com/gngrwzrd/UIImageLoader No LRU but it really isn't a requirement of a cache like this. Just remove images from disk that are older than a certain time period when app starts and that's good enough - UIImageLoader has helpers for that. And no HTTP HEAD, but it uses ETAG and modified-since headers properly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know that this thread has been answered, but I have tried a library that has worked great. I was using ASIHttpRequest before and the difference is big.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Also, if someone needs to Resize or Crop the remote images, and have the same features that SDWebImage provide, I have integrated SDWebImage library with UIImage+Resize library (by Trevor Harmon), and created an example project. I modified the code of SDWebImage to deal with transformations (crop, resize).

The project is public on https://github.com/toptierlabs/ImageCacheResize. Feel free to use it!

Comment: Making this the accepted answer since Dean mentioned ASI is deprecated :)

Comment: I tried the project in xcode 4.5, its giving error "unrecognized selector send to UIImage" for setImageWithURL.. I think its not linking to the protocol in this framework.. Any solution?

Comment: It was missing one of the methods in the .m, I have just released a new version fixing this. Make sure that you import "UIImageView+WebCache.h". If you have more issues let me know.

Comment: I don't believe SDWebImage checks if the image has been updated (using ETAGs)

Comment: Also, SDWebImage is still using NSURLConnection even after 3+ years of NSURLSession.

Answer (score 25):

EDIT : ASI has been deprecated now but @Tony's answer has a link to a library that seems to do most of this (disclaimer - I've not yet tried it and am going by @Tony's recommendation!)

---

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) does all of that :)

All you would have to do is add something like to the success callback

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];

// If the image is nil ASIHTTPRequest will let you remove the data from the cache
// but I can't remember off the top of my head how. Checkout the docs!
```

---

EDIT

And when you've finished it, you could always pop it onto github for the rest of us . . .

Comment: Ah good call, I didn't realise ASI had updated its caching stuff to handle all that new functionality!

Comment: Hmm, ASI doesn't cover requirement 2. that I can see.... it only has 'cache permanently' and 'cache for this session' options.

Comment: Cache size is just the size of the folder - that's not too tricky. And if you want more specific cache behaviour, just implement ASICacheDelegate ;) Why do you need such stringent requirements for an cache for an iOS app?

Comment: will ASIHTTPRequest check HEAD and reload?

Comment: I believe that's one of the possible caching strategies in their default cache implementation, yes (search for ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy in here : http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use ) :)

Comment: FYI, ASIHTTPRequest is now deprecated.

Comment: I posted a couple of alternatives.

Comment: My answer was deleted for some reason. I am reposting it.

Comment: Yea, I don't know why that happened - the person who deleted it didn't give a reason :(

Comment: Is that a question or a statement?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look recently for the sort of thing you describe -- either a general data cache, or an image centric one -- and didn't find much of interest. So you may have to roll your own to get all those features.

There's a various blogs posts and things detailing such things, such as 
http://davidgolightly.blogspot.com/2009/02/asynchronous-image-caching-with-iphone.html.

I take it you've considered the Three20 library? I don't think it would cover your requirements though.

Comment: Three20 has a nifty web image view :) thanks for pointing it out!