# Core data. How to organize relations beetween two resources. (one has urls of images used by another)

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I am developing a Forthsquare-like app for iOS. Using Core Data I am preparing the schemes for two resources: Place and Category. Each place belongs to category. Each category has *image_url* field containing a link to an image (hotel, restaurant and so on), so that every place being displayed on map uses its category image as an annotation marker.

The question is what approach to choose and how to organize the relations beetween these resources to have categories images (fetched through the *image_url* field) being cached, so they could be reused by all the places having the same category without a need to retrieve category image every time when every given place is loaded?

Being new to iOS & Core Data stuff I want to know if there are any good practices for accomplishing this kind of tasks.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at ASIHTTPRequest, with regards to caching images. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078193/ios-caching-and-loading-images-asynchronously. Or did you want to store the images within core data? Do you also need to know about the types of relationships there are? seems you need a one category to many places relation)

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my app in similar circumstances is add some properties to the Category (note you can save the image data directly in core data if the image is "small", or save it on disk and a filePath to the image if its "large"):

- bool fetchingImage
- NSInteger categoryID
- url (to fetch from)
- imageData or filePath

When the category is created and the url assigned, you can fetch the image (in the background) and set the fetchinImage flag to yes. Or you can wait til the first object requests the image, in which case you return nil but initiate the fetch.

When the image finally arrives, and you set it in this entity, you send a notification on the main thread that says categorID now has an image. Anyone listening for that can then request the image and make it viewable.