# image gallery from server in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm working on retreiving images from server and display it in ios.I select the image that I need to see on full screen it comes. But the problem is, once I go back, it reloads the whole images again from server. Are there any solution so as to save it in cache file for a while. I searched the whole internet for this, but didn't get a proper solution. Can any one please specify best tutorial for that. I'm newbie to ios

Comment: I guess, this is what you want
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078193/ios-caching-and-loading-images-asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

If each time you go back it reloads all the images agin from the server is probably because you may either create a new view or because you are calling to load the images from the method viewWillAppear instead of in the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the images here...

}
```

Instead of in here:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

If this doesn't not help, please provide us with some code.